# iOS Simulator - Can't log in with iCloud

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, icloud

I am trying to test the iCloud sync functionality of my app between a (real) device and the simulator, however I can't seem to log into iCloud. When I go to Settings->iCloud and enter my account details, it just gets stuck on 'Verifying'. However if I enter incorrect details, it brings up the invalid password prompt as expected.

Has anyone got a fix for this?

Comment: Are you on the Yosemite beta?

Comment: @KeithSmiley Are you implying it doesn't work in Yosemite Beta?

Comment: @chrs I'm not sure I had that issue in earlier betas. I haven't tried it since about beta 3.

Comment: Sometimes it takes a second before apps like Photos recognize the photos from your real device and start syncing; for me when it said “Uploading 5 Photos” it still didn’t catch the photos from my real device. So, try waiting a bit, perhaps opening another app, and it might work for you then.

Answer (score 132):

**TL;TR** Log into http://www.icloud.com and agree to the terms.

It works. But there are some additional steps needed:

At work I tried with my new apple id: at **work XYZ@mywork.com**. At first It didn't work even though I was able to access iOS dev center. I realised that it is required to access to http://www.icloud.com with such Apple ID and agree to the terms. After a few seconds I received a 'Welcome to iCloud' email to my work address and then I went back to the simulator and I **successfully logged in**.

BTW, for a personal account **XYZ@mac.com** I have for ages and use regularly it worked from the beginning probably because I have agreed to the terms a long time ago.

So not only @icloud.com of @me.com or @mac.com accounts work. All accounts work.

Comment: I just had log into iCloud.com from web browser and accept TnC.

Comment: Thank you. This was the solution.

Comment: Apple should have said exact error, there is a better way of error handling.

Comment: All these years later, and this is still a thing. Solution worked for me.

Comment: This needs to be upvoted to the moon... Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

1. Create an Apple ID from appleid.apple.com. You need an email address and a phone number to authenticate.
2. Login to icloud.com and accept terms and conditions.
3. Open Simulator, log in with your new Apple ID.
4. Done.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem today as I was trying to use iCloud + Core Data in the simulator (iOS 8.0, Mavericks). What I found out is that you should use, in the simulator, your @icloud.com e-mail. If you do that, you are able to login and use some iCloud functionality.

Answer (score -2):

This is Perfect Solution, it's 100% working

Create an Apple ID from appleid.apple.com. You need an email address and a phone number to authenticate.

Login to icloud.com and accept terms and conditions.

Open Simulator, log in with your new Apple ID.

Done.

Comment: Doesn't solve the problem, since i was already trying with a newly created, TFA activated and terms accepted account. 
Another weird thing is; Apple ID account manage page lists "Simulator" as a signed in device.